# Error in Octopus Deployment: Found multiple target elements, but the 'Replace' Transform only applies to the first match

Tags: octopus-deploy, web.config-transform

I have configuration file `(file1.config)` looking kind of like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <myelement>
     oldvalue
  </myelement>
</configuration>
```

I want to replace "`oldvalue`" with "`newvalue`". For this reason I have created a file `(file1.Development.config)` looking something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <myelement xdt:Transform="Replace">
     newvalue
  </myelemetn>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that when I deploy the package with Octopus Deploy I get the following error:

> Found multiple target elements, but the 'Replace' Transform only
>   applies to the first match

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by adding an xdt:Locator. So now my transformation file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <myelement xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="XPath(/configuration/myelement)">
     newvalue
  </myelemetn>
</configuration>
```